# .htaccess to redirect multiple domains, non-www. and non-https to the one single domain and preserve the path

Tags: .htaccess

I have a few old domains that resolve to the new site.  I just switched on SSL.  The old blog posts from old sites have been merged into the new site with the same paths.

I need .htaccess code to redirect multiple domains, non-www. and non-https to the one single domain with www and https.  Essentially, if it doesn't begin https://www.mavencomputers.com.au/ then redirect it to that whilst preserving the rest of the path, ie, not redirecting to home.

I currently have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^artisan\-solutions\.net\.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.artisan\-solutions\.net\.au$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.mavencomputers\.com\.au\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mavencomputers\.com\.au$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https://www.mavencomputers\.com\.au\/%1" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mavencomputers\.com\.au$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^images\.mavencomputers\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mavencomputers.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

You can test this file with [this tool](http://htaccess.mwl.be/).

Comment: Hi Florian
Thankyou.  The domain is actually .com.au, but I fixed this.  I also left out one thing.  I have images served from a sub domain images.mavencomputers.com.au.  This is also secured.  How do I add this in?

The code currently looks like this
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mavencomputers\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mavencomputers.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: If this solve your problem can you accept this answer to mark the Question as solved? [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)